# Ruby on rails / Active Record Query: return if field / record with array not contains element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got in my `TravelIdeas` table field `country_trips`, which includes the array of countries.

```
#<TravelIdea:0x007faa7bec40f0> {
                      :id => 9,
                :idea_key => "romantic",
               :idea_type => nil,
                    :cost => 2000,
              :created_at => Mon, 10 Jul 2017 07:48:49 UTC +00:00,
              :updated_at => Mon, 16 Oct 2017 08:10:47 UTC +00:00,
           :country_trips => [
                [0] "PL"
               ],
     :available_languages => [
                [0] "pl"
              ]
}
```

Local travels has nil in `:country_trips`, so I can ignore them:

`idea.where.not(country_trips: nil) if country.present?`

I've got my user destination country, so I want to show him all travel ideas which contains his dreamed country.

It would be sth like SQL server CONTAINS (column, 'country')

Probably this is not about `LIKE` because this is not about matching 1 country to 1 country.

For example
`country = user.destination_country`
means:
`country = "PL"`

but

```
:country_trips => [
   [0] "PL",
   [1] "DE"
   ],
```

I'm looking for sth like

`TravelIdea.where(country_trips: country)`

that will return all travel ideas which have this country in country_trips array :P

Comment: Did you use Rails' `serialize :country_trips` or did you use your RDMS built-in system for storing arrays? (like this for postgres https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/arrays.html)

Comment: I'm using postgres array

Comment: try this `TravelIdea.where('country_trips = any(?)', 'PL')` (you can google *postgres array rails* and you will find useful information like this one https://coderwall.com/p/sud9ja/rails-4-the-postgresql-array-data-type)

Comment: I tried this and it returns error 
output error: #<ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedObject: ERROR:  could not find array type for data type text[]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more a postgres question, section [8.15.5. Searching in Arrays](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/arrays.html) says:

```
SELECT * FROM sal_emp WHERE 10000 = ANY (pay_by_quarter);
```

In your case, you could write that as a SQL segment inside the `.where` method:

```
TravelIdea.where("? = ANY (country_trips)", country)
```